# Add dots to a boxplot chart (for outliers)

Tags: javascript, amcharts4

I would like to do a boxplot chart like [this one](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/box-plot-chart/) with AmCharts4 but in addition I want to add some dots to represent the outliers. What is the way to go? (I'm not asking for the identification of the outliers, just for the way to add some dots).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the way:

```
var outliers = [{
    "date": "2019-08-01",
     y: 125
  }, {
    "date": "2019-08-01",
     y: 128
  }, {
    "date": "2019-08-02",
     y: 130
  }];

var bulletSeries = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
bulletSeries.strokeOpacity = 0;
bulletSeries.data = outliers;
bulletSeries.dataFields.dateX = "date";
bulletSeries.dataFields.valueY = "y";
var bullet = bulletSeries.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
bulletSeries.tooltipText = "{valueY.value}";
```